# Increasing performance - comparing two large dataframes - nested for-loop

Tags: python, dataframe, performance

I have two dataframes, one which is about 58,000 rows (df2) and one which is 1000 rows (sic_tax).

df2 is has a column called capex_sic_code, which I want to compare to a column with the same name in sic_tax, if a match is found I want to take two values from other columns on the same row from sic_tax and create an identifier of the two (a_b).

To do this I have made a nested for-loop, but it takes forever to run given the large amount of data, 58000x1000. Any ideas of how I can make this more efficient?

Thinking that maybe one way could be to sort the sic-codes as they follow a four-digit pattern and as such I could sort them one direction for the first half and the other direction for the second half, shortening the amount of iterations.

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
        for index2, row2 in sic_tax.iterrows():
            if df2.iloc[index][df2.columns.get_loc('capex_sic_code')]==sic_tax.iloc[index2][sic_tax.columns.get_loc('capex_sic_code')]:
                   sdg_code = str(str(sic_tax.iloc[index2][sic_tax.columns.get_loc('SDG #')]))+'_'+str(sic_tax.iloc[index2][sic_tax.columns.get_loc('Direction (A, PA, PM, M)')])
                   a =  df2.iloc[index][df2.columns.get_loc('% of capex')]
                   df2.at[index, sdg_code] = a
                   break
```

Comment: I suggest you to experiment with this examples https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: @ZedIsDead, can you share a reproducible example of your two dataframes and the matching expected output ?

Comment: First sort the dataframe and then use a binary search. Even better: use a merge which has a `O(n + m)` complexity (while the sort is basically `O(n log n + m log m)` and your initial algorithm is `O(n * m)`). Since the sort is vectorized, it should be at least about 100-1000 time faster.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments. I managed to change it to be a lot faster by changing it to this code, which only uses one loop.

```
for index2, row2 in sic_tax.iterrows():
sdg_code = str(str(sic_tax.iloc[index2][sic_tax.columns.get_loc('SDG #')]))+'_'+str(sic_tax.iloc[index2][sic_tax.columns.get_loc('Direction (A, PA, PM, M)')])
df2.loc[df2['capex_sic_code'] == sic_tax.iloc[index2][sic_tax.columns.get_loc('capex_sic_code')], sdg_code]  = df2['% of capex']
```